# Can we add putImageData to fabric canvas instead of fromURL

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

`fabric.Image.fromURL(hc.toDataURL(), function(img) {
             // add image onto canvas
            Canvas.add(img);
            img.hasControls = false;
            img.hasBorders = false;
            img.hasControls = false;
            img.hasRotatingPoint = false;
            img.selectable = false;
        });`

Above code helps in rendering a image to canvas but I want to use something like putImageData/drawImage because I have to draw the image from another canvas . And as per real time operation using toDataURL for more than 5 MB images is very bad when performance comes to picture.

I also want to render the image on the middle of the canvas .
Fabricjs just takes the image toDataURL and renders it as it is.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fabric.Image()`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.html) just like the row [`ctx.drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) accepts a `canvasElement` as imageSource.

So you can just call it like

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Image(yourCanvasToDraw));
```

And if you want it centered in the canvas :

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Image(c, {left: canvas.width/2-c.width/2, top: canvas.height/2-c.height/2}));
```

Note that `ctx.getImageData`+`ctx.putImageData` is at least as slow as `ctx.toDataURL`which both are incredibly slower than `ctx.drawImage`

Comment: could you please add a jsfiddle with a small example . I am very new to Fabricjs and finding it difficult to work with when it comes to rendering images of more than 5 MB.

Comment: yes thank you very much , I am now able to render images superfastly. But one blocker , I dont want to pan the images (I mean I need to make selectable to false somehow for the image)