# Does the fabric image constructor load synchronously if passed a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have some code that creates a a new image and then I pass that to the fabric.image constructor. This works, but is async. Sometimes my image won't be loaded in time.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
fabric.Image(img);
```

I found in this other stack overflow post where I can just pass the canvas directly to the constructor:

```
fabric.Image(canvas);
```

[Can we add putImageData to fabric canvas instead of fromURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099145/can-we-add-putimagedata-to-fabric-canvas-instead-of-fromurl)

Would this be syncronous since my canvas will already be ready?

Answer (score 0):

Yes creating a *fabric.Image* from a <canvas> element directly is a synchronous operation.

```js
var scene = new fabric.Canvas('c');
scene.setHeight(200);
scene.setWidth(200);

var c2 = document.createElement('canvas');
c2.width = c2.height = 50;
c2.getContext('2d').fillRect(0,0,50,50);

var img = new fabric.Image(c2, {left:50, top:25});
scene.add(img); // will always work
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```